# Can I turn off a link in CSS, e.g. for a bookmarklet install page?

Tags: html, css, bookmarklet

I know how to use CSS to turn off or change the appearance of links on a web page (i.e. the anchor tags) but I'd like to turn them off completely. I'd like to do this for a bookmarklet install page. For example the [Delicious tools page](http://www.delicious.com/tools) has a bookmarklet you can drag onto your browser's favourites bar. But on the install page because the bookmarklet is inevitably a link you can also accidentally click on it if you meant to drag it. This could confuse novices so I'd like to turn off the link behaviour in CSS whilst leaving the HTML intact as it is needed for the bookmarklet to work.

I doubt this is possible as it is a behavioural change not a formatting change, but it would be great if it is possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible with plain CSS.

However, you could prevent the browser from following the link by using javascript/jquery:

```
$("a.bookmarklet").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

[**-- SEE DEMO --**](http://jsfiddle.net/KG8Ms/)

Comment: Even though your answer is valid because not all browsers support the following, the statement that it's not possible using css is not true. In Firefox, Safari and Chrome you can use "pointer-events: none;". This will cause a link to do nothing.

Comment: @JohannesLumpe This won't work in IE, and therefore I wouldn't class it as being possible in CSS as its not cross browser compatible http://caniuse.com/#search=pointer-events

Comment: Brilliant answer @Curt and follow-up comment Johannes. Thank you, I'll implement both!

Comment: @Curt I know that it's not cross compatible, as I already stated that inside my comment. I just wanted to point out that there is something coming up, with which you can do that.

Comment: pointer-events: none has the pretty disastrous side effect that in Chrome I cannot then drag the bookmarklet to the favourites bar! But no worries, Curt's JavaScript fits my requirements and learning about pointer-events was useful.